# How nice do we need to be? 7x77 nice?

Tags: discussion, political-correctness

I was reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback?cb=1) new policy, and maybe there will be a newer new policy.

But I was wondering, whenever someone insults me or my Church on this site, how nice do I have to be to them?  Personally, I don't like flagging comments I find find personally offensive, I prefer to leave them out there for blackmail in times like this:

[Point 1](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33447/what-is-the-scriptural-basis-of-the-tabernacle-with-the-blessed-sacrament-as-in/33485#comment88132_33485)

[Point 2](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32866/is-the-catholic-magesterium-in-favor-of-hard-liquor-prohibition#comment86120_32866) *although, that's not strictly a point in my favor*

So, given that not a few of you Protestants are in fact Protestants because you actually don't care much for the teachings Catholic Church (the feeling is heartily, if not emphatically reciprocal), how can we get over this and not all be insufferable twits?

Comment: **Mod Notice:** _<comments deleted>_ Normally I don't remove comments from meta, but I think the ones discussing the validity of a point about alcoholism in Catholic contexts is completely distracting from what should be discussed relevant to this meta question: what the "be nice" rule means on this site.

Answer (score 9):

I think the most relevant point to be made here is:

**Being nice != Agree**

Conversely **disagreeing does not give anyone the right to be rude** or belittling in their expression of such. One can* vehemently disagree on a point of theology or practice without waxing vitriolic about it. In most cases the scope of questions will be limited in such a way that there is no excuse for interjecting unwelcome opinions anyway, and the few questions that do cover scope that overlaps with disagreements should be dealt with in a purely academic fashion noting the points that various sides make without pronouncing one or another to be wrong in the absolute sense.

As an extension of this principle, for the purposes of this site "offensive" *must not* be defined in such a way as to include "expresses a view that goes contrary to my personal views". In other words **even outright blasphemous statements are not to be considered personally offensive**. By definition this site includes all manner of heterodoxy, and we all know we all disagree over what the boundaries of that even are. Instead "offensive" should be reserved for manners of expression that fall outside what the local culture of Stack Exchange defines as "nice".

<sub>* Here I use "can" in the sense that it is theoretically possible. In practice not all people seem to be capable of this, but those that cannot are not welcome to bring their failures to this site. They are welcome to participate only in so far as they are able to restrict their expressions to things that qualify as "nice".</sub>

Comment: +1 you of all the people on this site should know what it means to be unnecessarily impeded by the desire to right a perceived affront to ones religion and what to do about it.

Comment: @robert This meta post is not about the comment deletion practices. If you would like to ask a question or raise a concern about them the proper way to do that is to [open a new meta post](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) which you are free to do. That way the community has the opportunity to weigh in and actually settle issues. I'm [removing the discussion](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mvJ13.png) from here as it is not about my post at all.

Answer (score 0):

So I see one of my comments got deleted. Fair enough, it wasn't nice enough. I would like to be nicer. Anyone got advice for how to express shock and disgust when you see a doctrine which you believe doesn't offend you, but blasphemes God himself?

Comment: This should be a new question.

Comment: Agreed, though this is a possible answer: http://books.google.com/books?id=bYgQAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=the+ball+and+the+cross&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Qmc9VOHcOdStyATm2oGQDg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=%22why%20I%20broke%20his%20window%22&f=false

Comment: "see a doctrine which you believe doesn't offend you, but blasphemes God himself" That can be a difficult line, e.g. religious wars. There's a lot of blasphemy on this site, though what it is depends on the religion. If it is "just" blasphemy, there's probably nothing you can do here. If it is mean-spirited, then you could remind them the rules.

Comment: dannnii, it's not you (that's not nice enough).  it's not "Fair enough" at all.  and the "nice" moderator deleted my comment to this answer.